# Java GUI Design view not showing completely but code works

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am new to Java GUI I deigned and window and menu item using java design tool.But when I want to create window for menu item say `New contact` I did not find an option to do that in event handler so I did it manually by coding it.But when I go to design part and click on `New Contact` it does not show the window I created via code.

Here is the screen shot of deign view -when I click on `New Contact` nothing happens.[image]

Now in the source code when I run it I get the window I coded 
[image]

Is there any possible way I can make it work in design part? I did not find any option to do it in `Add Event Handler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not want a JFrame to show another JFrame -- that's a bad GUI design since it means that your application is actually two applications. Better to show a dialog window such as a JDialog. Please see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)
2. If you want to design a 2nd window, create a new Java program in NetBeans, one that creates this second window (again, better for it to be a JDialog, not a JPanel)
3. Give it a constructor that allows passing in the parent window, and then pass that to the JDialog super constructor
4. And then in your ActionListener code above, create a new object of this new program, passing in the current JFrame.

In the future, please post code as code-formatted text, not as an image, since this way we can copy, paste, compile and run it if we want, allowing us to better understand your code and your problem.

Comment: Is net beans better than eclipse for GUI ?

Comment: @donop: heck no, and in fact I use Eclipse, but I had assumed that you were using NetBeans since most of us that use Eclipse hand-code our GUI's.